# check/uncheck all checkboxes using another single checkbox using vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin8

I am new to Vaadin Framework. I create one project with vaadin 8.0.4. I created one grid with two columns but  i want add one texxfield column and one checkbox column.
i need to check all checkboxes when user click header cehckbox.

Comment: List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(new Person("Nicolaus Copernicus", 15),new Person("Galileo Galilei", 15), new Person("Johannes Kepler", 15))
         // Create a grid bound to the list
         Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
         grid.setItems(people);
         grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setCaption("Name");
         grid.addColumn(Person::getAge).setCaption("Year of birth");
           grid.addColumn(Person-> new TextField());
        layout.addComponents(grid);
         setParent(layout);

Comment: @jamesbond007 Please use the edit feature of your question to provide more information like code. Also, please close this question because you have added a new very similar but more concrete question already.